# make sure you're running a packager server or have included a .jsbundle file in your application bundle

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

I'm getting this issue suddenly, after that I'm not able to iOS build.
I have tried below more solutions but unable to solve them.

1. Delete node module and lock file and install it again.
2. Delete the pod file and pod lock and install it again.
3. delete the project and clone the previous running project and install npm and pod.
4. create a new project and compare it with my project, I have seen in my project **ResourceBundle-AccessibilityResources-React-Core-Info.plist**. missing and in the new project, it's shown me inside the pod folder.
5. My project shows me react-version 0.62.2 and new project version 0.63.2 I have to try with the change version also.

Please help me and suggest me out of the above.

Answer (score -1):

The solution that worked for me.

```
> sudo vim /etc/hosts
```

add

```
 # Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

then

```
> sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

the reason is I change  `hosts`